# Apply a function to 2 columns in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I want to apply a custom function which takes 2 columns and outputs a value based on those (row-based)

In Pandas there is a syntax to apply a function based on values in multiple columns

```
df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x.col_1, x.col_2), axis=1)
```

What is the syntax for this in Polars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In polars, you don't add columns by assigning just the value of the new column.  You always have to assign the whole df (in other words there's never `['col_3']` on the left side of the `=`)

To that end if you want your original df with a new column then you use the `with_columns` method.

you would do

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.struct(['col_1','col_2']) \
       .map_elements(lambda x: func(x['col_1'], x['col_2'])).alias('col_3'))
```

A struct is a dataframe inside a column of a dataframe. This is helpful because `map_elements` (and indeed all expressions) can only be invoked from a single column. The `map_elements` turns the struct, in each row, into dict and that becomes the input to your function. `map_elements` is for functions which take a single input and output a single value. (If you're using a vectorized function that expects something like a list and returns another list then you should use `map_batches`). Finally, you do `alias` on that to give it the name you want it to have.

Comment: And in many cases you don't need the .apply(lambda x:) part because you can use the Polars expressions to implement that logic. Expressions are typically faster than a .apply because they run in Rust rather than Python

Comment: This is great but doesn't work for object types, which is a shame in my case because I want to use it on arrays in columns. Instead I just used iter_rows and created a new df.